# From 3D Sparse to dense reconstruction

Tags: 3d, depth, surface, 3d-reconstruction

What are the possible ways to reconstruct a 3D dense model from a 3D sparse set of points. I tried interpolation but The 3D scene includes different objects in different groups of depths. What can I do to distinguish the objects?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you simplify the problem and/or be more specific about what objects are in the scene? What have you tried so far? Do you have a visualization of one or more samples of these sparse sets of points that you could share here?

Answer (score 0):

I would start from [Ball Pivoting](http://www.research.ibm.com/vistechnology/pdf/bpa_tvcg.pdf). Once you get a single Mesh representing different objects you can easily separate them using a triangle adjacency graph.